# Intel "Kernel processor" or "OS Kernel"

Tags: intel, terminology

I used to have an Intel data book from 1981. I gave it away to a friend, and he probably also lost it along the way.

In this book there was a data sheet for a component called "OS Kernel" or something like that. I always wondered (because it was not clear from the information) what kind of component that was, or should have been. I don't really remember anything else much about it. Looking on the internet for old Intel data sheets also seems like a lost cause, as it only brings up things from less than 10 years old.

Can anyone help finding pointers?

(I suppose that in that data book a whole lot of obscure Intel technology was described, like the iAPX 432).

Comment: Bitsavers has many Intel resources at http://www.bitsavers.org/components/intel/_dataBooks/ including ones from 1981 that look like the one you want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for was one the

**Operating System Processors (OSP)**

While advertised as one item, called *Operating System Firmware (OSF)*, it was rather a two chip system, consisting of one of the basic x86 real mode processors (8086/88 or 80186/188), and one of the OSP. They themself are composed of a [Multibus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multibus) compatible *Control Unit (CU)*, holding

- Data Buffers,
- Address Latches,
- Bus Interface and
- Control/Status Logic

and a secondary part called *Operating System Unit (OSU)*, containing

- a 16 KiB ROM with OS (kernel) code
- an 8259 compatible Interrupt Controller (PIC)
- three 8254 compatible Timer used as

  - System Timer
  - Delay Timer
  - Baudrate Generator

[image]

An instant system, just add

- RAM
- I/O
- Application Program

stir and run :)

There were two versions:

- iRMX OS Processor 80130
- CP/M-86 OS Processor 80150

A Datasheet for the 80130 can be found at various sites, for example [datasheetspdf.com](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/502121/Intel/D80130/1). An overview of the [iRMX OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMX_(operating_system)) can be found [here](https://bitsavers.org/pdf/intel/iRMX/iRMX_86_Rev_4_Nov_1981/iRMX_86_V4.0_Overview_Mar82.pdf)-

Comment: Ah, for the days when the OS was so obviously correct you could bake it into chip to be soldered into your system (not a ROM/PROM/EPROM in a socket ...)

Comment: I presume these were mainly used for embedded systems?  The iRMX one obviously, but also the CP/M one?

Comment: @davidbak would say so. after all, desktop systems (or servers) do not gain much hard coded OS - in fact, they are all about maxing out free RAM, so any ROM taking up address space is a liability. Like BIOS once boot is done.

Comment: @davidbak Obviously correct? Nah, if it didn't do what you needed, you just worked around it. Unlike a modern OS, the OS in those days wasn't in control: the application code had full control of the machine, just using the OS as a handy helper.

Comment: Might also have been called something like the AP-130. I've seen suggestions that the 80150 didn't really exist, and I've not come across the 80130 in real life.

Comment: @davidbak That era lasted till the mid-2000's if you knew where to look. The Japanese would very commonly mask their firmware in. Even today, they do much the same. Check out this [2021 Honda recall](https://static.nhtsa.gov/odi/rcl/2020/RCRIT-20V439-8875.pdf) where they need, essentially a probe station, to reflash the instrument cluster.

Comment: @user71659 What's the meaning of 'mask' in context with FLASH?

Comment: @Raffzahn Mask as in mask ROM, either as a standalone device or microcontrollers were available with integrated mask ROM. (e.g. "[Hitachi H8S/2628M (128 kilobytes of on-chip mask ROM)](https://www.hitachi.com/New/cnews/E/2002/1212/1212.pdf)")

Comment: @user71659 I know what a mask ROM is. And that's what confuses me. A mask ROM can not be flashed as its content is non changeable. So, what's the meaning in context with the 'reflash' menationed?

Comment: @Raffzahn Modules in many new cars can be flashed via the Internet and cellular data. Otherwise modern cars typically flash modules via the OBD-II port. Honda made an instrument cluster that not only couldn't be flashed externally, they omitted a port on the module to flash. So when a safety issue came up, flashing had to be done by breaking a hole in the back of the instrument cluster to access pads on the PCB with a precision fixture. That's very close to treating the flash memory as non-reprogrammable.

Comment: @user71659 sorry, but that's simply not anything like mask - not even like (E)PROM programmes, as either does mean that the physical chip has to be removed and exchanged or reprogrammed. Just because a wire is needed doesn't make it even remotely similar - if at all it makes it was more secure :)